# Solve complex equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm having problems in solving the following equations

```
A+B+C=0
D+E+3G=0
A+D+G=0
B+E+G=0
C+G=0
(0.74j)A-(0.74j)B-(22.5+10.89j)D+(3.75j)E=1
```

I have tried the solve command but it gave me an error for the last equation.

Comment: Then it would be helpful to know what error you received.

Comment: please post the error message to avoid down vote.

Comment: also check if you have the symbolic toolbox, or it isn't going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fairly trivial linear problem of the form `Ax = b`, with

```
%    A          B  C             D     E  G
A = [1          1  1             0     0  0
     0          0  0             1     1  3
     1          0  0             1     0  1
     0          0  0             0     1  1
     0          0  1             0     0  1
     0.74j -0.74j  0 (22.5+10.89j) 3.75j  0];

b = [0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1];

% x = [ <your factor A>
%       <your factor B>
%       <your factor C>
%       <your factor D>
%       <your factor E>
%       <your factor G>];
%
% We have to solve for x.
```

You can solve this most easily with Matlab's backslash operator:

```
>> x = A\b

ans =
     -0.017048398623080 + 0.009391773374804i % A
      0.000000000000000 - 0.000000000000000i % B
      0.017048398623080 - 0.009391773374804i % C
      0.034096797246161 - 0.018783546749607i % D
      0.017048398623080 - 0.009391773374804i % E
     -0.017048398623080 + 0.009391773374804i % G
```

Observe that

```
B == 0
C == -A == E == -G == D/2
```